# Detecting when a link has been clicked with PHP

Tags: php, hyperlink, detect, click

I have built an in browser engine that will retrieve pages without executing server side scripting... seems ridiculous, I know, but I'm doing this as part of a school project.

The problem that I am having is that once it displays the page if a link is clicked it will bring you to www.their-site.com instead of www.my-site.com?site=www.their-site.com.

Basically I need my php page to detect if a link is clicked and, if so, add "www.my-site.com?" before it so that all sites will still be rendered without all the server side scripting. Is their any way to do this?

---------------EDIT---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Ok I guess I wasn't clear enough the first time sorry about that.

I have made a php page that will display the contents of any site without executing the server side scripting that belongs with that page. This allows you to get around those annoying news articles that allow you to have a glimpse at them for two seconds and then a login box appears. the problem is once you've accessed the pages if you click any links you are connected to their server and the scripts turn back on. I want MY php to execute, not THEIRS

Comment: I'm a bit confused here, first you say `retrieve pages without executing server side scripting` then you say `Basically I need my php page to detect if a link is clicked`. What's the involvement of PHP? Are you using PHP to generate the initial page that then in turns loads the other pages with JS?

Comment: Um, PHP runs on the server, not in the browser. If you want the links to look like that, you'll need to generate the page with them looking like that. Otherwise, you'd need to write some javascript that's running in the user's browser.

Comment: `$('a').each(function(i){this.href="http://redirect.com?"+this.href})`

Answer (score 0):

You need to know what you want first.
You say no server side scripting, then you mention php.

To do this, I don't think you can do it with just js.

You need to get the pages, using php, depending on what exactly, modify them such that when a link is clicked, it sends an ajax call to another page. This will require either regex replacement or the use of htmldom.

When a link is clicked, it should send the ajax response to the php page which can then request tha page, make modifications and send it back to the browser. You can then use js to replace the page contents.

Comment: OK maybe I should explain a little better. I have made a php page that will display the contents of any site without executing the server side scripting that belongs with that page. This allows you to get around those annoying news articles that allow you to have a glimpse at them for two seconds and then a login box appears. the problem is once you've accessed the pages if you click any links you are connected to their server and the scripts turn back on. I want MY php to execute, not THEIRS